# Glassfish v2 can't find all ciphersuites

Tags: glassfish, certificate, suse, diffie-hellman, glassfish-2.x

I have 2 seemingly identical glassfish installations (installed using the same installer, same OS - SLES 11 SP2 - with the same installed packages and updates, same JRE/ JDK, same web applications deployed in the same way, similar keystores - different PKs, same method of getting/ signing, etc.), however, the two installations have 2 different sets of available ciphersuites. I believe that this is causing Server A to give a "Server has a weak, ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key" error when visiting the application.

Server A:

```
Available Common Ciphersuites:
        SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

    Available Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman Ciphersuites:
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

    Available 40 bit and 56 bit Ciphersuites:
        SSL_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DES_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
        SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA

    Available ECC Ciphersuites:
    none
```

Server B:

```
Available Common Ciphersuites:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

    Available Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman Ciphersuites:
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

    Available 40 bit and 56 bit Ciphersuites:
        none

    Available ECC Ciphersuites:
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

What could be causing this difference in available ciphersuites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `asenv.conf` ({glassfish installation}/config/asenv.conf) was defining `AS_JAVA=...` and glassfish was using this instead of the version of java defined in the path and JAVA_HOME. Pointing `AS_JAVA` to the correct jre solved the issue.